# Is the Mumford-Tate group determined by its $\mathbb{Q}$-points?

Tags: algebraic-groups, hodge-theory

Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Hodge structure and $MT \subset GL_V$ its Mumford-Tate group. Let $I \subset \mathcal{O}_{GL_V}$ be the ideal of functions vanishing on $MT(\mathbb{Q})$.

> Is $\mathcal{O}_{GL_V}/I$ equal to the Hopf algebra of $MT$ ?

Comment: The Mumford-Tate group is a connected affine algebraic group. Are there connected affine algebraic groups that do not have this property?

Comment: Not in characteristic zero.